# Impossible to compile a python script in .apk with buildozer (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes')

Tags: python, buildozer

I'm trying to compile a python program in .apk with buildozer. But I've been stuck for a while on this error during compilation.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fiche_lecture_app/armeabi-v7a --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 32, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 934, in build_arch
    self.install_python_package(arch)
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 950, in install_python_package
    shprint(hostpython, 'setup.py', 'install', '-O2',
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/fiche_lecture_app/armeabi-v7a --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 32, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/gabriel/fiche_de_lecture/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Many others before me have stumbled across the same error, but their solution of installing various dependencies and additional tools just wasn't enough. What I don't understand is that when I run ctypes or _ctypes in the python interpreter, I don't get any error, which is a sign that the module is pre-installed.